# LaTeMplate macro based on LaTeX macro

Tags: header-footer, titles, boxes, kerning

I am trying to produce yet another LaTeX-like macro. It was supposed to based entirely on the original LaTeX combination with one little change, and to just work fine. Long story short, it didn't. As I don't know much about all those fancy commands in the LaTeX and TeX macro, I turn to you. All I want to do, is change the X of TeX to an M. An MWE follows.

The original definition as found in source2e.pdf is commented out, but essentially, this is the one I am trying to make work. Well, the way I did it is a bad workaround, because it's (almost) fine for the title, but then I want to display my creation in my fancy header, and there, of course, the A is way too big. So I need to work with the original definition, which uses relative sizes and can't just have the nice raisebox workaround.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%\def\latemplate{L\kern-.36em{\sbox\z@ T\vbox to\ht\z@{\hbox{\check@mathfonts\fontsize\sf@size\z@\math@fontsfalse\selectfont A}\vss}}\kern -.15emT\kern-.1667em\lower.5ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emMplate\@}

\def\latemplate{L\kern-.3em\raisebox{.5ex}{\large A}\kern-.14emT\kern-.1667em\lower.5ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emMplate\@}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[L]{\footnotesize\latemplate}

\title{\latemplate{} fo' ma momma}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\clearpage

\section{first section}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

The document title looking fine:

[image]

The header not so much:

[image]

Comment: you need `\makeatletter` to access commands with `@` in their name

Comment: simple, yet effective. that did the trick. you guys seem to always be online. amazing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to compute a smaller font based on the current font size, which is done by `\check@mathfonts` and using `\sf@size`.

The following parameters are tailored for Libertinus Serif (the successor of Linux Libertine), other fonts will need different values. Adjust them to suit.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\LaTeMplate}{%
  L\kern-.27em
  {\sbox\z@ T%
   \vbox to\ht\z@{\hbox{%
     \check@mathfonts\fontsize\sf@size\z@
     \math@fontsfalse\selectfont
     A%
   }\vss}%
  }%
  \kern-.12em
  T\kern-.12em
  \lower.35ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125em Mplate%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\LaTeMplate

{\footnotesize\LaTeMplate}

{\Large\LaTeMplate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I shall look for Libertinus Serif. I forgot to put my definition between `\makeatletter \makeatother`.